# Is zenne oud better for starters than the regular one?

Tags: learning, oud

I wonder if zenne oud (a smaller version of the regular instrument) is better for the starters in terms of ease of learning.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of simply providing an opinion, if the new student in question is particularly small in stature, than like any other instrument that comes in more than one size, I would say yes.  I say this especially in light of the instrument's bowl-back design and student arm length considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Zenne oud can be used not only for new learners but also for professionals. Although it is designed for women, many important oud masters may also prefer zenne oud. For this reason, Zenne oud can be preferred not only for learning but also continuously.